# How to Split the Process of an Enormous Loop Between Multiple CPU Cores in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing

My situation is, that I will need to parse & process hundreds (possibly thousands) of json files as fast as possible, and would rather not do that in c++ (in which parallel processing seems much easier).

the code is something along the following lines:

```
var dir = fs.readdirSync('./folder') //making array of all json files in relevant folder
for(i=0; i < dir.length; i++){
let somejson = fs.readFileSync(`./folder${dir[i]}`) //storing file content in a variable
let parsedJSON = JSON.parse(somejson); //parsing said variable
someheavyfunction(parsedJSON)
} //performing heavy computations on parsed content of an individual json file
```

what I'm finding hard to figure out, is how can I effectively split this process between all my machine's CPUs? Say the length of the dir array is divided by 8, and each portion assigned to a different core? Everything I could find about cluster module seemed to refer to dealing with multiple users communicating with the server from their web client\browser. In my case, there will be very few users communicating with the server, rarely more than one at a time.
*note that the server will be linked to some messaging system (maybe a Discord\Telegram bot, haven't decided yet)
Any pointers will be appreciated !

Edit: while trying to use `const {Worker, isMainThread, parentPort} = require('worker_threads')`

```
if(isMainThread){
  const worker = new Worker('./chunk1.js') //code that processes only a subset of the json files in the relevant folder
  worker.on('message', (msg)=>{
    console.log(msg)
  })
}
else{
  parentPort.postMessage('Working')
}
```

The server seems to be using the 3000 port more than once

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
```

Even though the chunk1.js has absolutely no code that has mentions port 3000 in any way.

Solution:

````
exec('node chunk1.js', function (err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log('sub script executed', stdout)
})

exec('node chunk2.js', function (err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log('sub script executed', stdout)
})

exec('node chunk3.js', function (err, stdout, stderr){
  console.log('sub script executed', stdout)
})``` //etc for every CPU core
````

Comment: We would have to see exactly what `someheavyfunction()` is doing to have any idea.  The answer lies in breaking up what that function is doing into separate chunks of work.  The cluster module is not built for this type of application.  You will have to manually create worker threads or processes, manually break the work into chunks and then send each worker a chunk of work to process.  When it's done, send it another chunk until all chunks are processed.

Comment: To put it plainly, someheavyfunction() does a few thousand comparisons between different values in the json file, and changes values of variables within the function at certain junctions. There shouldn't be anything preventing the processing of each json file separately, because the output of processing any json file has no effect on output of processing any other json file.

Comment: I've tried using 
`if(isMainThread){
  const worker = new Worker('./chunk1.js') 
  worker.on('message', (msg)=>{
    console.log(msg)
  })
}
else{
  parentPort.postMessage('string')
}`
//./chunk1.js being same code that processses a subset of the contents of 
```var dir = fs.readdirSync('./folder')```, but my port 3000 wasn't having it 
```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000 
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000 ```

Comment: You apparently have some code in your thread that is calling `server.listen(3000)` and trying to start a server.  Since you haven't shown that code, there's nothing I can do other than to say that the worker code should ONLY be code that processes incoming `worker.on('message', ...)` messages and that worker code shouldn't be importing anything that does anything other than help it process its messages.

Comment: I think that adding const {jsonArray, someheavyfunction} = require('./server.js')
might have triggered the port related operations in server.js, because when I simply coppied the code that defines and assigns someheavyfunction & jsonArray respectively, it ran without error :)
Does it really mean that when I require('somescriptfile.js') it executes all the code before providing the module.exports part of it? As in, the `http.listen(3000, ()=>
console.log("listening on port ***3000"))` is trigerred twice that way?

Comment: When you `require()` in a module in a new thread, it will reinitialize that module from scratch.  As I said before, you need to only import into your  thread just the things you need for the thread processing, not anything else.  So, just separate out `someheavyfunction()` into its own module and import that.